# Grok pattern file

Tags: logstash-grok

I'm trying to get pattern grok on my log file data 
this is the message log

```
116.50.181.5 - - [18/May/2019:09:05:32 +0000] "SHARP56" 50 245 "INFO: System componement ready for use" 23 "A4" "/user/admistrator/68768.pdf" "INFO: No ERROR TO SHOW"
```

I've tried this grok pattern but it didn't works

```
%{IP:client}  %{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] %{WORD:name} %{NUMBER:X1} %{NUMBER:x2} %{WORD:msg} %{NUMBER:X3} %{WORD:format} %{WORD:path} %{WORD:label}
```

the output file that I want should look like this

```
{
client = 116.50.181.5
timeStamp = 18/May/2019:09:05:32 +0000
name = SHARP56
x1 = 50
x2 = 245
msg =INFO
format = A4
type = pdf
label = INFO: No ERROR TO SHOW
}
```

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following:

```
%{IP:client} - - \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"%{DATA:name}\" %{NUMBER:X1} %{NUMBER:x2} \"%{GREEDYDATA:msg}\" %{NUMBER:X3} \"%{WORD:format}\" \"%{DATA:path}\" \"%{GREEDYDATA:label}\"
```